# Stripe for Woocommerce - credit cards work fine,but not Google Pay, why and how to fix?

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I installed the official plugin by Woocommerce, and visa/mastercard payment method is working, but when I try Google Pay - it fails. I see the popup with my address, the price, the delivery method, click to buy, and it's the error.
Of course I enabled stripe in settings.

I tried to deactivate plugins.

Then I tried to install the plugin with high rating - Payment Plugins for Stripe WooCommerce.
It doesn't work at all.
From it I've read that for Google Pay I need merchant id.
I pasted my own - didn't help.
Maybe that's the reason - clients don't have Google Pay, so maybe they have to integrate it with their stripe account? Cause the card  was integrated. I don't know.

In the first plugin there is nothing about merchant id, at least cards work, and the second plugin doesn't work at all - cards too.
Maybe someone already faced with the same issue?
The log is about nothing

```
2023-09-27T13:40:08+00:00 DEBUG 
====Stripe Version: 7.6.0====
====Start Log====
payment_intents request: Array
(
    [amount] => 150
    [currency] => eur
    [payment_method_types] => Array
        (
            [0] => card
        )

    [capture_method] => automatic
)

====End Log====


2023-09-27T13:40:19+00:00 DEBUG 
====Stripe Version: 7.6.0====
====Start Log====
payment_intents request: Array
(
    [amount] => 150
    [currency] => eur
    [payment_method_types] => Array
        (
            [0] => card
        )

    [capture_method] => automatic
)

====End Log====
```

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to the support teams for these plugins to confirm they offer support for Google Pay as you which, and to ask for guidance on implementing that if it's available. I'm not sure what plugin you were referring to initially when mentioning an official plugin, but these are the Google Pay instructions I was able to find for the second one you referenced: https://docs.paymentplugins.com/wc-stripe/config/#/stripe_googlepay

Comment: I write everywhere - there and there too